# How to properly place web-scraped data into a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

**Problem:** I have used BeautifulSoup to scrape a Wikipedia page for the meat consumption per capita for each country in the world. Having trouble putting it into a data frame using Pandas - my data frame is coming up blank.

Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_meat_consumption

**Goal:** Place web scraped data into a data frame

**Code:**

```
url_meat1='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_meat_consumption'
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url_meat1)
soup= BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")# parse the HTML from our URL into the BeautifulSoup parse tree format
print(soup.prettify()) #print results of the web page scrape

table_meat1 = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable')

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]

for row in table_meat1.findAll('tr'):
    cells=row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==3:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))

df_meat1=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Country'])
df_meat1['kg/person (2009)']=B
df_meat1['kg/person (2017)']=C
df_meat1
```

I get a blank data frame...
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOfzM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with this `for` loop:

```
for row in table_meat1.findAll('tr'):
    cells=row.find_all('td')
    if len(cells)==4:
        A.append(cells[0].a['title'])
        B.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[3].find(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
                 Country kg/person (2009) kg/person (2017)
0                Albania             None                 
1                Algeria             19.5            17.33
2         American Samoa             26.8                 
3                 Angola             22.4                 
4    Antigua and Barbuda             84.3                 
..                   ...              ...              ...
183            Venezuela             76.8                 
184              Vietnam             49.9            52.90
185                Yemen             17.9                 
186               Zambia             12.3                 
187             Zimbabwe             21.3            13.64

[188 rows x 3 columns]
```

Same data in a `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Can you explain what you did? Trying to understand the code.

Comment: Sure...I have made 2 changes. 1. Changed `if len(cells)==3:` to `if len(cells)==4:`, because there are no cells with length 3. All the cells have a length of 4. 2. Changed `A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))` to `A.append(cells[0].a['title'])`, because the `title` attribute contains the country name.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sushil. You have been a great help!